# Why the search bar placeholder text is misaligned to show in top of search bar in iphone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

Here I have attached the screen shot for search bar placeholder, which is misaligned in the search bar. Can you please help solve this problem:

What reason the placeholder text is over on their search bar icon. Following are the 2 lines of code added for the alignment:

```
[self.obj_searchbar_verify setSearchTextPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0,10)];

[obj_searchbar_verify setPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(140, 0) forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch];
```

Comment: Did you add any code that would affect the appearance?

Comment: No, just above two line of code used for align the text.

Comment: can anyone help from this issue.

Comment: I encountered the same issue.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot please?